# I don't understand what "temp <<= y;" does in this javascript program

Tags: javascript

I need someone to help explain what the line temp <<= y; does in this bit of javascript code and how i could recreate this program in Little Man Computer.

```
var temp = 14;
var y = 2;
temp <<= y;
document.write(temp);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Left_shift

Comment: Refer [this](https://ideone.com/R16HkR)

Answer (score 1):

It is the [left shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Left_shift_assignment) assignment operator. It shifts the number in binary format to the left and adds that many zeros to the end. So, in your case:

```
var temp = 14; // which is 1110 in binary
temp <<= y; // transforms it in 111000
document.write(temp) // the number in base 10 is 56
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation :D